# How to reload the project in xcode

Tags: xcode, command-line-interface

I am using a CLI tool to add new folders and files in a Xcode Project but even though I am able to see it in finder, its not reflecting in Xcode.

[image: This is the folder that I created using the CLI tool]

And this image is the Xcode project view

[image: This is the view]

As you can see the folder that I made using the CLI tool is not reflected in Xcode. How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should only add files and folders by dragging them into Xcode. If you add them directly in Finder, Xcode won't detect them.

Comment: Use SPM, and have it generate your xcodeproj from your sources. `swift package generate-xcodeproj`